# Traits inside Models

Tags: php, laravel, oop, coding-style, traits

For example I have a model class. I want it to be `Timestampable`. It means a model must have `created_at`, `updated_at` fields and getters for them.

```
<?php

trait Timestampable {

    protected $created_at;
    protected $updated_at;

    public function getCreatedAt() {}
    public function getUpdatedAt() {}   

}

class User extends Model {

    use Timestampable;

    protected $id;
    protected $name;
}
```

Is it ok? Or I have to move `timestampable` fields in to the model?

[Authenticatable Trait (Laravel)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Auth/Authenticatable.php)

In Laravel they don't place their fields in traits, but only some of them. Of course it works while these fields exist in class where our trait was used. But we lose some advantages in IDE autocompletion and make our code ambiguous.

Comment: Eloquent models already have timestamp handling enabled by default.  Investigate the HasTimestamps trait..

Comment: If you think, that "model" is a class, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: As mentioned, this particular trait already exists. That being said, the framework itself does use traits to compose a model so there's nothing wrong with you doing the same. As far as the IDEs are concerned PHPStorm does have some intelligent detection of where the traits are used and provides some auto completion based on that but in general I don't know how well supported this is in other IDEs

Comment: @Devon it's just an example, nobody says that I'm using Laravel, I just gave it as an example, everybody to understand what I meant.

Comment: @MarkYeltsin then don't tag laravel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all Model have already property `created_at` and `updated_at` because the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` has already use the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps` which define the `getCreatedAtColumn` and `getUpdatedAtColumn` methods [HasTimestamps method getCreatedAtColumn](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ecf2999b2aff80a72dd45c2a48b7c4db694fc6ac/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php#L112)

You don't have to define your own `HasTimestamps` it isn't important because all the implementation that provide that behavior already exist

Comment: It was just an example. I don't use Laravel. I just said that I saw like Laravel's traits coded and asked if it ok.

Comment: If your are not using Laravel that ok. But you must define trait in the case which you will have other Models that will be Timestampable, else you can define directly that properties and methods on the User Model

Comment: Yes, I'll have another models with timestampable behavior. All I want to understand is how I should define properties. Should I define them directly in trait or I need to define them in Model and use traits' getters blindly?

Comment: Yes, that's. If you define the properties in `Trait`. You will not repeat yourself, because you will have just to put the `use Timestampable` in your model that will attach getters and properties at once in all your Model, instead of add the `use` and also specify properties